# how to use variables in jQuery select event in other javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, database

I am really new to jquery and javascript... I want to use the four variables in myairFunction to calculate something and those four variables store values retrieved from database.
How can make use of these values in my function ?
The function does not work. even if i test as follows, it printed nothing. where's wrong ?

```
$("#airradio1").click(function(){

$("#aircalc").click(function(){
    $("#airanswer").html(lat1);

    });

});
```

html :

```
 <div id="calculator">
  <h3>Air Travel</h3>
  <div id="air">

 <input type="radio" name="frm" id="airradio1" checked="check" onclick="setairform1()">Enter Individual flights(more accurate) <br>
 <input type="radio" name="frm" id="airradio2" onclick="setairform2()">Enter numbers of flight(faster)<br>
    <form id="airform1">
    <div>
        From
        <div class="textinput">
            <input type="text" id="dept" name="departure" placeholder="City name or aiport code" >
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        To
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="dest" placeholder="City name or airport code" >
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        Via
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="via" placeholder="City name or airport code" >
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="trip" value="roundtrip">Round-trip <br>
            <input type="radio" name="trip" value="oneway">One-way
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        Number of flights/passengers
        <input type="text">
    </div>

    <div>
        Class
        <select style="width: 82px">
            <option selected="selected">Economy</option>
            <option>Business</option>
            <option>First</option>
        </select>
    </div>

           <div><button type="button" id="aircalc" >calculate</button></div>


    <div id="result">
        <div id="totalresult"> Total Emission: 
            <p id="airanswer">0 </p> lbs CO<sub>2</sub> </div>
    </div>
```

here is the php :

```
$strSQL = "SELECT display, lat, longi FROM airport WHERE display LIKE '$term%'";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
$json=array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
$json[]=array('value'=>$row['display'],
          'label'=>$row['display'],
          'lat'=>$row['lat'],
          'longi'=>$row['longi']
          );
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var lat1;
    var long1;
    var lat2;
    var long2;

    var a;
    $('#dept').autocomplete({
    source:'source.php',
     minLength:1,
     select:function(evt,ui){
        lat1=ui.item.lat;
            long1=ui.item.longi;

            }
     }); 


     $('#dest').autocomplete({
     source:'source.php',
     minLength:1,
     select:function(evt,ui){
        lat2=ui.item.lat;
            long2=ui.item.longi;

     }
     }); 



     $("#airradio1").click(function(){
        $("#aircalc").click(function(){
            myairFunction1(lat1,lat2,long1,long2);

        });

    });


     $('#via').autocomplete({
        source:'source.php',
        minLength:1

     }); 
});

 function myairFunction1(lat1,lat2,long1,long2){

    co2 = lat1+lat2+long1+long2;
    document.getElementById("airanswer").innerHTML = co2;

}
```

Comment: add your html code as well. also please tell us where your javascript compared to your html elements are

Comment: I don't see you even attempting to obtain the 4 vars from server side

Answer (score 0):

without seeing the information requested in the comments its nearly impossible to say what's going wrong. but the nested click function looks suspect. if you can target the element directly then why the nested listener?

```
$("#airradio1").click(function(){
    $("#aircalc").click(function(){
        myairFunction1(lat1,lat2,long1,long2);

    });

});
```

instead just add the event listener directly to the #aircalc element:

```
   $("#aircalc").click(function(){
        myairFunction1(lat1,lat2,long1,long2);

    });
```